# Grails : Updating Index.gsp from another controller

Tags: grails, groovy

My Grails app is using version 2.3.6

In this app there's a Controller class:

```
class UserOrderController {

def index(Integer max) {
        params.max = Math.min(max ?: 20, 100)       
        respond UserOrder.list(params), model:[userOrderInstanceCount: WorkOrder.count()]
    }
}
```

Now in another Controller i am accessing the **UserOrder** objects and filtering based on product ID. Product ID is a string property in UserOrder domain class.

The other controller is:

```
class UserOrderFilterController {

def getUOBasedOnID () {

  // Here i get a new list for **UserOrder**
  // Now i want to draw the UserOrderController page with the new list
}
}
```

I am pretty new to Grails and not sure how to do this.

Should i be creating a new INDEX function in UserOrderController class and pass the new list?

Like shown below:

```
class UserOrderController {

def index(Integer max) {
        params.max = Math.min(max ?: 20, 100)       
        respond UserOrder.list(params), model:[userOrderInstanceCount: userOrder.count()]
    }

 def index(List UserOrder) {

   // create page???
}

}
```

**UPDATE:**

The **UserOrderFilterController** has it's own **index.gsp** file. 
What am doing is: Accessing all the objects for UserOrder domain class and filter them based on a property.

Now in the index.gsp of **UserOrderFilterController** i will show the total number of objects/orders found. This number will be shown with a hyperlink using **href** and when the user clicks on it, it will go to **index.gsp** page of **UserOrderController** with only the filtered **UserOder**'s displayed.

So what am expecting is:

```
<a href='${createLink(controller:'UserOrder', action:'index')}'>%s</a>
```

A **href** like shown above with a **params** field that will have the filtered list of **UserOrder**'s.

I have no idea how to add the params/list to **href**. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each `action` in Grails has a matching `view`. Duplicating actions is asking for trouble. If you have some *new* functionality that deserves a page of its own, then you should create a new action and a new view.

If it *belongs* on the home page, then put it through the same `index` method.

Note that in grails, you simply pass the values to the `.gsp` page and the `.gsp` page is what handles the formatting of the data. Your `action` should have absolutely 0 knowledge of the structure of the view. This is a core concept in MVC.

In this case, you can redirect to a controller, as per [the docs](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.4.x/ref/Controllers/redirect.html). The one that should interest you the most is this:

```
redirect(controller: "yourController", action:"index", params=[filteredList: filteredList]);
```

This will redirect to the existing index action in your UserOrderController, and pass in the filtered list. From there, you can have something like..

```
if(params.filteredList) {
    // You know this came from the filtered controller, so display this and don't
    // make a DB call.
}
```

**Point to Note**

- The structure of your grails application worries me. Why have you got an entirely separate controller for simply filtering data?

**Edit**

Taking the `createLink` approach can be improved a bit. Instead of..

```
<a href='${createLink(controller:'UserOrder', action:'index')}'>%s</a>
```

You can use the `g:link` functionality:

```
<g:link controller="UserOrder" action="index" params=['filteredList':filteredList]>%s</g:link>
```

Comment: Please see UPDATED content in my original question.

Comment: In the index.gsp file of UserOrderController it uses the EasyGrid tables to display data. In my **getUOBasedOnID** function in the **UserOrderFilterController** class i have a local list of **UserOrder's**, how can i make sure that this list itself is populated in index.gsp at **UserOrderController** ???

Comment: You're adding more and more complexity to your example. Can you please create a *complete* explanation of your code?

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to create new controller for filter `UserOrderFilterController`, you can do

```
class UserOrderFilterController {

def getUOBasedOnID () {

  //get filtered list
    respond filteredList, [view:'userOrder/index',model:[userOrderInstanceCount: filteredListCount]]
  }
}
```

You can see more about respond [here](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.3.x/ref/Controllers/respond.html).

Comment: Please see UPDATED content in my original question.